# PHP: Textfile to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to create a multidimensional array from a textfile? If yes, how could that be achieved?

I am struggling with the 'Country' (Austria AT, Australia AU, Belgium BE) as this is only listed once whenever a new country starts. Hope that makes sense. The number of entries per Country can vary.

That would be a typical example of the textfile.

```
Austria AT
Vienna-S03-I01
30 Users
Vienna-S03-I02
31 Users
Australia AU
Sydney-S01-I01
49 Users
Sydney-S01-I02
46 Users
Belgium BE
Brussels-S01-I01
39 Users
Brussels-S01-I02
32 Users
```

That's what I am trying to achieve:

```
    0 => 
     0 => AT
     1 => Vienna-S03-I01
     2 => 30 Users
    1 => 
     0 => AT
     1 => Vienna-S03-I02
     2 => 31 Users
    2 => 
     0 => AU
     1 => Sydney-S01-I01 
     2 => 49 Users
    3 => 
     0 => AU
     1 => Sydney-S01-I02
     2 => 46 Users
    4 => 
     0 => BE
     1 => Brussels-S01-I01 
     2 => 39 Users
    5 => 
     0 => BE
     1 => Brussels-S01-I02
     2 => 32 Users
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried?

You could try something like this:

```
$handle             = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
$output             = [];
$currentCountryCode = '';
$currentSet         = [];
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $line = trim($line);
        if (preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z,\'\"]*)\s([A-Z]{2})$/', $line, $matches)) {
            // var_dump($matches);exit;

            // This is a country line, we need to reset the current set
            $currentSet         = [];
            $currentCountryCode = $matches[2];
        } else if (preg_match('/^([a-z\-0-9]*)$/i', $line, $matches)) {
            // If the current set is empty, add the current country code
            if (count($currentSet) === 0) {
                $currentSet[] = $currentCountryCode;
            }
            // This is a region line
            $currentSet[] = $line;
        } else if (preg_match('/^([0-9]{2}\sUsers)$/', $line, $matches)) {
            // This is a users line
            $currentSet[] = $line;
            // We need to add the set to the output array
            $output[] = $currentSet;
            // And reset it
            $currentSet = [];
        } else {
            $error = 'Could not this match line! Need to update the regexes!' . PHP_EOL . var_export(['line' => $line], true);
            throw new Exception($error);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
var_export($output);
```

Tested in PHP7.0.20

```
| => php test.php
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    0 => 'AT',
    1 => 'Vienna-S03-I01',
    2 => '30 Users',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    0 => 'AT',
    1 => 'Vienna-S03-I02',
    2 => '31 Users',
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    0 => 'AU',
    1 => 'Sydney-S01-I01',
    2 => '49 Users',
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    0 => 'AU',
    1 => 'Sydney-S01-I02',
    2 => '46 Users',
  ),
  4 =>
  array (
    0 => 'BE',
    1 => 'Brussels-S01-I01',
    2 => '39 Users',
  ),
  5 =>
  array (
    0 => 'BE',
    1 => 'Brussels-S01-I02',
    2 => '32 Users',
  ),
)
```

You might need to adjust the regexes as I haven't actually tested this script. Also, this will only work if the rest of your data is structured exactly as the first lines you provided. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really like the idea. I tested it and it is working with the exception that it doesn't add the Country Code. This is what I get: `0 => 
     0 => Vienna-S03-I01
     1 => 30 Users
1 => 
     0 => Vienna-S03-I02
     1 => 31 Users
2 => 
     0 => Sydney-S01-I01
     1 => 49 Users
3 => 
     0 => Sydney-S01-I02
     1 => 46 Users
4 => 
     0 => Brussels-S01-I01
     1 => 39 Users
5 => 
     0 => Brussels-S01-I02
     1 => 32 Users` It is not triggering the error message though

Comment: It appears like `if (count($currentSet) === 0) {` is never triggered because the set is never empty.

Comment: Not trying to be mean, but I think you should also pay attention to the other answer above, as one can name and further process the arrays as required by the OP.

Comment: @khofm I updated the answer, I had to switch the order around of these `// If the current set is empty, add the current country code
            if (count($currentSet) === 0) {
                $currentSet[] = $currentCountryCode;
            }
            // This is a region line
            $currentSet[] = $line;`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can work for you (assuming that you will get $lines through file read). I have tested this with http://phpfiddle.org/, you can also run this code there and see if the output is what you want

```
<?php

$lines = ("Austria AT
Vienna-S03-I01
30 Users
Vienna-S03-I02
31 Users
Australia AU
Sydney-S01-I01
49 Users
Sydney-S01-I02
46 Users
Belgium BE
Brussels-S01-I01
39 Users
Brussels-S01-I02
32 Users"); // Get the file content

    $arr = [];
    $header = FALSE;

$lines = preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $lines);

    foreach($lines as $line){
        if(preg_match("/(.*)\s[A-Z]{2}/", $line))
            $header = $line;
        if($header != $line)
            $arr[$header][] = $line;
    }

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

The output that I get is something like:

```
Array ( [Austria AT] => Array ( [0] => Vienna-S03-I01 [1] => 30 Users [2] => Vienna-S03-I02 [3] => 31 Users ) [Australia AU] => Array ( [0] => Sydney-S01-I01 [1] => 49 Users [2] => Sydney-S01-I02 [3] => 46 Users ) [Belgium BE] => Array ( [0] => Brussels-S01-I01 [1] => 39 Users [2] => Brussels-S01-I02 [3] => 32 Users ) )
```

You can then access individual elements like:

```
print_r($arr['Austria AT']);
```

which returns:

```
Array ( [0] => Vienna-S03-I01 [1] => 30 Users [2] => Vienna-S03-I02 [3] => 31 Users )
```

or

```
print_r($arr['Austria AT'][1]);
```

which returns

```
30 Users
```